# Bubble chamber event (higher velocity)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In the figure you can see two electron. Which of the two electrons has the higher velocity?
Does the magnetic field run into the plane of the paper or does it run out of the paper? And why do the orbits of the electron and positron have opposite curvatures?

[image]

Comment: Write down the force law of a moving charge in a magnetic field, and convince the reader you appreciate it...

Answer (score 1):

You do not give a link for the picture. In such pictures the magnetic field is perpendicular to the surface of the picture.

It is a drawing of an interaction of a gamma ray hitting a field in the bubble chamber and creating an electron positron pair at the vertex of the interaction and a gamma ray which ends up in the free electron positron pair.

> Which of the two electrons has the higher velocity

The smaller the curvature in the magnetic field the higher the momentum .

> Does the magnetic field run into the plane of the paper or does it run out of the paper?

It is perpendicular to the paper. The direction up or down defines whether it is an electron or a positron . One can tell in  a complete picture because there will be small scattered electrons on some  tracks defining the curve. In this event the straight line leaving the vertex must be an electron ( that supplied the field for the pair creation).

> And why do the orbits of the electron and positron have opposite curvatures?

Because of the algebra of the motion of [charge in a magnetic field,](https://scienceready.com.au/pages/charged-particles-in-magnetic-fields) as electrons and positrons have opposite charges.